# CurrentRegion excel VBA issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have the follow code:

```
Sub SelectRegion()
   Worksheets("Searches").Activate
   Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Select
End Sub
```

the "region" has 106 rows and 36 columns full of data
If I run it, I get the **"Unable to get the CurrentRegion property of the range class"**.
Both perplexing and frustrating.

Comment: Does your `CurrentRegion` start in "A1"? If not, use `UsedRange` instead.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The start of the range is "a1". In fact, I created another work book filled all the cells again with the same result.

Comment: My real goal is understanding why "CurrentRegion" doesn't work on my machine. I simplified the code so it is easy replicate. it's a straightforward, basic macro which should run.

Comment: Any pivottables, listobjects, filters, slicers in that range?  Can you manually select the currentregion (select A1 then Ctrl+A) ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I tried running it and it worked fine for me. The problem has something to do with your worksheet or workbook. I suggest starting with a new workbook and adding complexity or reducing the complexity of your current workbook. Do it one step at a time and you will find the root cause.

Comment: Technoman, It was a solo workbook with only that macro and some test data. Nothing else was open.